# Automapper fails using a Generic Method - Event though the Generic Type is not used

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, automapper

I am trying to make a generic method to map properties on similar classes.

The following works:

```
    Private Shared Sub CreateVAccessMap()
        For Each prop In GetType(WorkRecordHeader).GetProperties()
            Mapper.CreateMap(Of VAccess, WorkRecordHeader)().ForMember(prop.Name, 
                Sub(m) m.MapFrom(Function(s) s.GetFieldValue(prop.Name)))
        Next
        Mapper.CreateMap(Of VAccess, WorkRecordHeader)().ForMember(Function(dest) dest.Id, Sub(opt) opt.Ignore())
    End Sub
```

But when I add a generic identifier it fails (`Argument types do not match`) even though I am not using that generic type:

```
    Private Shared Sub CreateVAccessMap(Of T)() 'Note change here
        For Each prop In GetType(WorkRecordHeader).GetProperties()
            ' The following line fails on every property...
            Mapper.CreateMap(Of VAccess, WorkRecordHeader)().ForMember(prop.Name, 
                Sub(m) m.MapFrom(Function(s) s.GetFieldValue(prop.Name)))
        Next
        Mapper.CreateMap(Of VAccess, WorkRecordHeader)().ForMember(Function(dest) dest.Id, Sub(opt) opt.Ignore())
    End Sub
```